# Expandable text field in acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, forms

I would like to create a pdf with text fields that expand in height but when you are finish typing that they revert back to there original size so as not to cover anything up or flow the  rest of my file off the page.

Is this do-able? I have Adobe Livecycle Designer but know little to nothing about it, have only tinkered. I also have Acrobat Pro X.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have extensively searched for a way to do this, no such luck. I'm not sure it's possible, but I would love to be proven wrong :)

Comment: What do you mean, have you set the properties for the field ?

Comment: Do you want to create the PDF Form ?

Comment: @Bala I believe this is the behavior that Jim is looking to achieve within a PDF form: http://jsbin.com/ewekef/1/edit

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding! JohnB I checked out your link, know nothing about coding. How can I utilize the code provided at http://jsbin.com/ewekef/1/edit?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to get expandable forms (as in a PDF document that will reflow/expand as the content inside of it grows) is with Adobe's [LiveCycle Designer](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle.html) product. This is a Windows-only application that provides an XML-based PDF format which allows for content reflow and expandable forms. You can use LiveCycle Designer without needing or using the rest of the LiveCycle Enterprise products.

To create a re-flowable form, make sure your document is saved as a Dynamic XML PDF format and then organize your form into sections of subforms (see [Adobe's help page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/DesignerQuickStartTutorials/WS92d06802c76abadb6fe0558212a19a83673-7fe1.2.html)). This helps position elements in relationship with each other. Configure subforms that you want to "expand/reflow" by going to the Object Palette for the selected subform and making sure it's set to "Flowed". Again see [Adobe's help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/DesignerHelp/WS92d06802c76abadb11a7f71129b8b00825-7fed.2.html) manual for LiveCycle Designer. Also make sure your form elements (i.e. your text input areas) inside these subforms are configured to expand with the content. Then save and test to ensure it works.